# Run out issue while getting run

Tags: cricket

During getting run, non striker batsman reaches over striker ends crease and hitting striker ends stumps. And he is not trying to get another run.
Is he run out..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's clearly not run out as:

1. he had made his ground at the striker's end.
2. the wicket cannot be put down by the non-striker's person or bat ([Law 29.1.1](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-29-the-wicket-is-down/) explicitly states "the striker" in sections 29.1.1.2 to 29.1.1.4).t

However, if the non-striker hitting the stumps was "wilful", he would be out for obstructing the field ([Law 37](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-37-obstructing-the-field/)):

> Either batsman is out Obstructing the field if [...] while the ball is in play, he/she wilfully attempts to obstruct or distract the fielding side by word or action.

This is a judgment call on the part of the umpires; I would personally be pretty harsh on this - running towards the stumps is wilful, even if the batsman intended to stop. Tripping and falling into the stumps would probably not be wilful.

I don't believe the Laws cover the case of a batsman *accidently* disrupting the wicket while running, other than the possibility of the striker being out hit wicket if it occurs while setting off for the first run. It would pretty clearly be against the spirit of the game to attempt further runs in that scenario.